# Python 3 проблема с установкой Linter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ошибка при установке Linter microsoft visual code

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rde6gm6p\\typed-ast\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rde6gm6p\\typed-ast\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-tama4kaj' --python-tag cp38
       cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rde6gm6p\typed-ast\
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast
  copying typed_ast\ast27.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast
  copying typed_ast\ast3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast
  copying typed_ast\conversions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast
  copying typed_ast\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast
  package init file 'ast3\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast\tests
  copying ast3\tests\test_basics.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast\tests
  running build_ext
  building '_ast27' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for typed-ast
  Running setup.py clean for typed-ast
Failed to build typed-ast
Installing collected packages: typed-ast, astroid, pylint
  Running setup.py install for typed-ast ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rde6gm6p\\typed-ast\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rde6gm6p\\typed-ast\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e9eh3zpe\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=
         cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rde6gm6p\typed-ast\
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast
    copying typed_ast\ast27.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast
    copying typed_ast\ast3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast
    copying typed_ast\conversions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast
    copying typed_ast\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast
    package init file 'ast3\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast\tests
    copying ast3\tests\test_basics.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\typed_ast\tests
    running build_ext
    building '_ast27' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rde6gm6p\\typed-ast\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rde6gm6p\\typed-ast\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e9eh3zpe\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Строка "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required..." как бы намекает...

Comment: я не могу почему-то найти Microsoft Visual C ++ 14.0 зашел на официальный сайт там его нету на других тоже где скачать ?

Comment: Ну как же? в тексте ошибки же ссылка есть. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16